# Qualtrics API not downloading all responses

Tags: api, qualtrics

I have code to download responses to a survey from Qualtrics using the getLegacyResponseData API request. 10 people have completed the survey, but when I run the API request, I only get 3 responses. This happens no matter what. I've tried:

- Setting a StartDate and EndDate
- Changing the API version used
- Specifying a LastResponseID

None of these return the missing responses. Those 3 responses are the only ones I ever get.

I can see the other 7 responses in Qualtrics under "Recorded Responses" and I can also manually download their responses using the "Download Data" function.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I figured it out. The issue is that for some reason Qualtrics isn't understanding that I want all the responses under the default response set. I specified the default response set as the response set and got all the records. Annoying, but it works.

Edit (11/20/2017): see my comment below for anyone looking for the answer. This is related to response export caches and not response sets.

Comment: Actually no, coming back to this 2 years later this was not the issue. The issue has to do with Qualtrics caching responses. They have some workarounds documented in the latest API documentation: https://api.qualtrics.com/docs/create-response-export